# Two different table join view

Tags: oracle, join, oracle-sqldeveloper, union, create-view

```
CREATE VIEW KC_Salary AS 
SELECT DEPT_SNAP.DEPTNO,
        DEPT_SNAP.DNAME, 
        Sum(EMP.SAL) as Avg_Salary, 
        COUNT(EMP.SAL) as Total_Salary, 
        EMP.DEPTNO 
FROM DEPT_SNAP
union
select Sum(EMP.SAL) as Avg_Salary, 
       COUNT(EMP.SAL) as Total_Salary,
       EMP.DEPTNO 
from EMP;
```

I'm trying to make a view with two tables that are different. I'm getting the

> SQL Error: ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result
>   columns
>        1. 00000 -  "query block has incorrect number of result columns"

If you have any tips or ideas what is happening please help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to combine the results of two statements - of which the first one has five, but the second one just three columns. Both need to have the same number of columns. (And the columns in the same position need to be of compatible types.)

As a side note: Your column aliases do not really seem to match the functions applied.

### Update

Summing up the comments, you are probably looking for something like:

```
CREATE VIEW KC_Salary AS 
SELECT
  D.DEPTNO
  , D.DNAME 
  , AVG(E.SAL) AS Avg_Salary
  , SUM(E.SAL) AS Total_Salary
FROM DEPT_SNAP D
JOIN EMP E
  ON D.DEPTNO = E.DEPTNO
GROUP BY D.DEPTNO, D.DNAME
;
```

Comment: I'm mainly going off the home work the tables have completely different attibutes but the DEPTNO.
Create a view called KC_Salary.  This view should contain the deptno, dname, 
            along with the average salary named Avg_Salary and total salary named 
            Total_Salary grouped by department number.  Copy the create view statement to 
            your answer template

Comment: It seems, you do not really need a `UNION` but a `JOIN` to start with. Next, a `GROUP BY` might be necessary (depending on whether the aggregates are requested for each department or for the whole company). Last not least: `AVG` for **Avg_Salary** and `SUM` for **Total_Salary**.

Comment: CREATE VIEW GiftsList
AS
SELECT  b.name user_from,
        c.name user_to,
        d.name gift_name,
        d.price gift_price
FROM    gift a
        INNER JOIN users b
            ON a.user_from = b.id
So something like this then?

Comment: In general: Yes. But you would need to get your table aliases correct. You select, e.g., **c.name**. However, you have just **a** for **gift** and **b** for **users**. In other words: An `INNER JOIN` should get you moving - but your gift example would not work without adjustment.

Comment: oh ok Thank you very much. I'm just having problem with the "EMP.SAL as "Avg_Salary"" parts I tried AVG(EMP.SAL) as "Avg_Salary" and the group by AVG(Avg_Salary);

Comment: Whether or not you need a `GROUP BY` depends on the exact requirements. Guessing from the bits, you provided, you'd probably `GROUP BY DEPT_SNAP.DEPTNO, DEPT_SNAP.DNAME` (replacing **DEPT_SNAP** by its alias, if you defined one). Remember, the `GROUP BY` needs to include all non-aggregate columns from your `SELECT` list.

Comment: ok but what I meant was for the Sum and as parts I'm getting error with those because EMP.SAL has to be called as and have a sum and avg in it.

Comment: Check, please, `SELECT deptNo, AVG(sal), SUM(sal) FROM Emp GROUP BY deptNo;` and continue from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW KC_Salary AS 
SELECT DEPT_SNAP.DEPTNO,
               DEPT_SNAP.DNAME, 
               Avg(EMP.SAL) as Avg_Salary, 
               Sum(EMP.SAL) as Total_Salary
FROM DEPT_SNAP 
    ,EMP
WHERE DEPT_SNAP.DEPTNO = EMP.DEPTNO
GROUP BY DEPT_SNAP.DEPTNO, DEPT_SNAP.DNAME
```

Comment: Complete shot in the dark.. it would've been helpful to know the structure of your tables and also what the desired output was.